# How can I change the currency on the App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I bought my iPhone 4 in France, but since then moved to the US.  I have changed my address, my phone number etc. associated with my Apple ID, but the prices of the apps in the App Store still appear in euros.  This is a problem because I would like to purchase apps using my US credit card, without my US bank making me pay foreign currency fees.

So. I've looked on the internet and here but came up short on how to effect a switch.

How do I change the currency on the App Store?  Or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In iTunes, go to the iTunes Store tab, and click on your account in the top right corner, as shown. [image: Click on account information at the top of the iTunes Store page in iTunes]
2. After typing your password, you will see this page. Click 'Change Country or Region', and change it. All done!

[image: In account information, click 'change country or region'.]

**Note:** if you have any iTunes Store credit, you will have to spend all of it before it lets you switch countries.

Comment: This is more of a permanent switch. You could alternatively just try scrolling to the bottom of the main iTunes store (on a computer) and click the flag icon to see if you can simply switch stores. This doesn't require you to spend anything down as long as Apple is willing to sell to your ID in the desired country.

Comment: Yes, but I think the OP was asking for a permanent switch as he has moved to the US and has a US credit card.

Comment: I do too - had I thought it was the main thrust of the question I would have edited your answer (in addition to up voting it). I wanted to comment in case it helped someone else. Feel free to incorporate it if you feel it helps, but having it as a comment seems the right place to point out an unlikely but potential shortcut to the process.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried both suggestions (by PartiallyFinite and by bmike), one after the other, and the currency changed to US dollars on my computer, but not on my phone though I both restarted and synchronized the latter after making the change.

Comment: Are you logged into your iTunes account on your phone? Try logging out and logging back in again (Settings > Store).

Comment: Logging in and out did not do the job on its own, but this really helped me figure out that Settings > Store > Apple ID > Show Apple ID > change region etc., and then switching off and back on my phone worked.  Thanks!!

Comment: But How do you convert it if you like in euro 0,27 to a another country

Answer (score 0):

## IPad 2018

I was looking into this in my new Ipad 2018. Things have changed...

All you need to do is to sign in with your Apple ID.

1. Open the apple app store, then go to your account (rounded icon)
2. Then press on Account
3. Country/Region
4. Change Country or Region

This should work for you!

Answer (score -2):

This should help. Found this on the apple support website.
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201266

Comment: Please include a brief quote from the Apple Support site you linked here, as your answer would lose value if the link dies

Comment: The link addresses how to change the payment method associated with an Apple ID. The question involves changing the currency displayed, which means that they would need to change the country associated with their Apple ID. The accepted answer from four years ago resolves the question.

Answer (score -3):

Go onto apple website then onto your profile and change the country.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How do you get from the Apple website on to 'your profile'?